# Expected declaration error at the do { line using Swift 3

Tags: swift

I am receiving an expected declaration error at the do { line. I have tried researching this and read over the Apple developer information for Swift 3 on try/catch statements but have not been able to figure this out.

Here is the code:

```
class Calculator: ViewController {

    var display = "0"
    var numerator : Float?
    var denominator : Float?
    var total : Float?


    enum divisionErrors: Error {
        case inf
        case nan
    }

    func divide(num: Float, by denum: Float) throws -> Float {
        guard num != 0 else{throw divisionErrors.nan}
        guard denum != 0 else{throw divisionErrors.inf}

        let computedValue = num / denum
        return computedValue
    }

    do {

        catch divisionErrors.inf {print("Error")}
        display = "0"

        catch divisionErrors.nan {print("Error")}
        display = "0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're attempting to use a `do` statement in the body of a class, whereas it should only be in the body of a function. For the sake of the argument, I'll put this in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
class Calculator: UIViewController {

    var display = "0"
    var numerator : Float?
    var denominator : Float?
    var total : Float?


    enum divisionErrors: Error {
        case inf
        case nan
    }

    func divide(num: Float, by denum: Float) throws -> Float {
        guard num != 0 else{throw divisionErrors.nan}
        guard denum != 0 else{throw divisionErrors.inf}

        let computedValue = num / denum
        return computedValue
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        do {
            try total = divide(num: numerator!, by: denominator!)

        } catch divisionErrors.inf {
            print("Error")
            display = "0"
        } catch divisionErrors.nan {
            print("Error")
            display = "0"
        } catch {
            assert(false, "Other Error")
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, when you `do` something, you must also `try` to do something that could fail. Afterwards, you close the `do` with some `catch` statements on your errors. Like a `switch` statement, your `catch` cases must be exhaustive. You will have errors when trying to compile without that final `catch` rounding up the rest of the possible errors, as potential errors transcend the scope of your `divisionErrors` enum.

You might also want to error check numerator and denominator to be sure they exist. I just force unwrapped them for the sake of the exercise.

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now. I am new to programming and I appreciate the advice.

Comment: If my answer satisfies the question, please mark the question as answered!